# Azure devops pipeline include local resource in build

Tags: git, azure-devops, pipeline

I do have a pipeline build of Android application from external GIT (other git). Everything works fine with normal build. However there is a need to prepare a build with included SQLite database and zipped content. I am adding via PowerShell couple entries to csproj file to include the files into the build. 
Following lines are added to csproj:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\prepared_db.sqlite">
  <LogicalName>prepared_db.sqlite</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\prepared_content_file.zip">
  <LogicalName>prepared_content_file.zip</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

The problem is that these two resources are quite big size and are static. I do not want to take them from the GIT (I am building also app for iOS, Windows in two GIT branch versions without these additional two contents ) all the time, especially that it takes a bigger while to download sources from GIT.

Is it the way somehow to store it as Library file and then instead of getting file from GIT include the files from Library during build ?

Comment: You're looking for something called Git LFS. Or use an artifact management system such as Artifactory to store them as versioned artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for hint. Anyway i found other solution - i put the files on IIS server and used copy file to put into the artifact.

Comment: I installed market task called "Download a File" by Fizcko. With that task i copy files from IIS server (files are under the username and password). The files are copied into the artifact. With Powershell script i am modifying the csproj file to attach resources to project before a build.